# Call parent form function?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# window program with 2 forms. The base form (Form1) has a function to refresh (`RefreshView`) the view. Clicking buttons will bring up Form2. After clicking say an "Apply" button on Form2, how can I call `RefreshView` function that exists in Form1? Both forms are open by the user.

Form1 code in `Form1.cs`:

```
namespace MonitorCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void RefreshView()
        {
            //refresh code etc
        }
    }
}
```

Form2 in `Form2.cs`:

```
namespace MonitorCSharp
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(String args)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2Text = args;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            //I want to refresh here
        }
}
```

I have tried various code including:

```
((Form1)this.ParentForm).RefreshView();
```

To call the refresh function, but so far everything gives me a runtime error. Am I missing something?

I get no compile errors. The runtime error is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MonitorCSharp.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MonitorCSharp.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: @EricJ. Was just editing that in, it's in the question now

Comment: You want to call the refresh after closing ? I am not sure if any code after closing will get executed.

Comment: @sdeep It will.  Code that affected the form itself would likely not be observable, but closing the form doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent form can attach an event handler to it's child's `FormClosed` event handler to execute code when it's closed:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Form2 child = new Form2();
        child.FormClosed += (s, args) => RefreshView();
        child.Show();
    }

    public void RefreshView()
    {
        //refresh code etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you simply need to pass a reference to Form1 when you construct Form2.

Find the constructor for Form2, that is most likely:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

And add a parameter to it, so it now reads:

```
public Form2(Form form1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _form1 = form1;
}
```

And add a private field in your Form2 class:

```
private Form1 _form1;
```

Then when you create Form2 from your Form1.cs, you should use

```
new Form2(this);
```

where "this" represents the current instance of Form1.

And to access RefreshView from Form2, you call

```
_form1.RefreshView();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828238/how-can-i-access-a-property-or-method-of-foo-from-bar

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullReferenceException.

Chances are very good that you never initialized `this.ParentForm`.

When Form1 creates Form2, ensure that you set that property appropriately.

One way to do that is to create a constructor for Form2 that takes an instance of its parent, e.g.

```
public Form2(Form1 parent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ParentForm = parent;
}
```

When creating the child form from the parent form,

```
Form2 child = new Form2(this);
```

Comment: `this.ParentForm = parent;` → 'System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ParentForm' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, this works for me. (The called function is not static.) (VS2010.)

Main form:

```
internal partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    using (Form2 f2 = new Form2(this) { Icon = this.Icon })  // Instantiate the child form.
    {
        f2.someUpDown.Maximum = foo;  // (Optionally write data to the child form.)
        f2.ShowDialog();  // Show the child form and wait until it closes.
        ...
        bar = f2.someUpDown.Value;  // (Optionally read data from the [closed] child form.)
        ...
    }  // (Destroy the child form.)
```

Child form:

```
internal partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _parent;  // (need this variable)

    internal Form2(Form1 parent)  // (the default constructor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _parent = parent;  // Save the argument.
        ...
        someUpDown.Maximum = Form1.foo;  // (Optionally read data from the parent form.)
        Form1.bar = someUpDown.Value;  // (Optionally write data to the parent form.)
        ...
        _parent.myProcedure(arg1);  // (Optionally call myProcedure() in the parent form.)
        ...
    }

    private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // (callback from event loop)
    {
        ...
        someUpDown.Maximum = _parent.foo;  // (Optionally read data from the parent form.)
        _parent.bar = someUpDown.Value;  // (Optionally write data to the parent form.)
        ...
        _parent.myProcedure(arg1);  // (Optionally call myProcedure() in the parent form.)
        ...
    }
```

If I change `private Form1 _parent;` to `private Form _parent;`, it's invalid.

If I change `internal Form2(Form1 parent)` to `internal FormTubeSelection(Form parent)`, it's invalid until I also change `_parent = parent;` to `_parent = (Form1)parent;`

Almost everywhere, you access Form1 fields and methods with the `_parent.` prefix; the `Form1.` prefix is invalid. EXCEPTION: Access Form1 fields in the constructor as `Form1.foo`; `_parent.foo` is invalid there.

If you only need to call the procedure in the main form when the child form closes, it is easier to call it *from* the main form, right after `f2.ShowDialog()`. If the call is conditional, code in the main form can test data in the child form and/or the return value of `f2.ShowDialog()`, until you dispose of f2.